Translation invariant function has zero directional derivative
Let $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function which is also seen as a superposition operator $f\colon L^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$. We know that this superposition operator is directionally differentiable.
Suppose $f$ satisfies $f=0$ on $(-\infty, 0]$ and
$$f(u) = f(u-v)$$
for all functions $v$ such that $v \geq 0$ and $v \leq u^-$, where $u^-$ means the negative part of the function $u$ (using the decomposition $u=u^+ - u^-$).
Now from this, how can I conclude that
$$f'(u)v = 0$$ for all functions $v$ as specified above?
I have seen this claim in a paper, but sadly I can't find it any longer...
